# Traer correo PERS e INST que se encuentran en la tabla EmailAddress

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

Estoy intentando armar una query para unos usuarios (tabla PEOPLE) con sus correos electrónicos (tabla EmailAddress). En la tabla PEOPLE existe un atributo llamado PEOPLE_ID y en la tabla EmailAddress existe el atributo PeopleOrgId con los cuales hago un inner join, pero resulta que en la tabla EmailAddress existen 2 tipos de correos que son INST y PERS. Cuando corro mi consulta me trae 2 registros del mismo usuario, uno con el correo INST y otro que trae el correo PERS, pero si loe digo que solo me traiga le INST solo me devuelve un registro con su correo INST.

¿Cómo podría armar para traer ambos correos electrónicos, pero que no me duplique al usuario?

Se que el modelado de la tabla está muy mal, pero es lo que hay.

Les anexo mi intento de consultas y las tablas que estoy utilizando.

> Esta consulta solo trae Correo INST

```
$this->db_sqlserver->select('p.PEOPLE_ID AS matricula, p.FIRST_NAME, p.MIDDLE_NAME, p.LAST_NAME AS a_paterno, p.Last_Name_Prefix AS a_materno, e.EmailType, e.Email AS email_institucional');        
            $this->db_sqlserver->from('PEOPLE AS p');
            $this->db_sqlserver->join('PEOPLETYPE AS pt', 'pt.PEOPLE_ID = p.PEOPLE_ID');
            $this->db_sqlserver->join('EmailAddress AS e', 'e.PeopleOrgId = p.PEOPLE_ID');
            $this->db_sqlserver->where('pt.PEOPLE_TYPE', 'STUD');
            $this->db_sqlserver->where('e.EmailType', 'INST');
            $this->db_sqlserver->limit(50);
```

> Esta consulta tare los 2 correos que necesito, pero me duplica los
> registros.

```
$this->db_sqlserver->select('p.PEOPLE_ID AS matricula, p.FIRST_NAME, p.MIDDLE_NAME, p.LAST_NAME AS a_paterno, p.Last_Name_Prefix AS a_materno, e.EmailType, e.Email');        
            $this->db_sqlserver->from('PEOPLE AS p');
            $this->db_sqlserver->join('PEOPLETYPE AS pt', 'pt.PEOPLE_ID = p.PEOPLE_ID');
            $this->db_sqlserver->join('EmailAddress AS e', 'e.PeopleOrgId = p.PEOPLE_ID');
            $this->db_sqlserver->where('pt.PEOPLE_TYPE', 'STUD');
            $this->db_sqlserver->limit(50);
```

**Tablas**

> Tabla PEOPLE

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Tabla EmailAddress

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que me puedan orientar.

Saludos y bonito jueves.

Comment: ¿Puede usar http://sqlfiddle.com/ para armar un ejemplo reproducible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Básicamente tienes que leer la tabla dos veces, cada una con su restricción.

```
Create table People(People_code char(1), People_id varchar(15), People_code_id varchar(15))

Create table EmailAddress (EmailAddressId int, PeopleOrgId varchar(15), emailType varchar(4), Email varchar(100));
go
insert into People (People_code, People_id, People_code_id)
values
('P','0001','P0001'),
('P','0002','P0002'),
('P','0003','P0003');

Insert into EmailAddress (EmailAddressId , PeopleOrgId,emailType, Email)
values
(18500,'0001','INST','email1'),
(18501,'0001','PERS','email2'),
(18502,'0002','INST','email3'),
(18503,'0003','PERS','email4');
go
```

Si haces un left join, en vez de una inner join porque puede que alguien no tenga correo, puedes armarlo dos veces diferentes, una para cada tipo de correo y así extraer la info en la misma linea.

```
Select *
From People left join EmailAddress e1 on people.People_id = e1.PeopleOrgId and e1.emailType = 'INST'
            LEFT JOIN EmailAddress e2 ON people.People_id = e2.PeopleOrgId and e2.emailType = 'PERS';
```

[image: Resultado]

Aunque el ejemplo esta hecho directamente en TSQL, no te costará adaptarlo.

El ejemplo se basa en la premisa de que solo tienes de 0 a 1 correos de cada tipo, por usuario. Si hubiera más, entonces no sería correcto.